# chrome: use sourcemaps to debug contentscript

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-chrome-extension, google-chrome-devtools, source-maps

I'm developing a webextension for Chrome. The code is written in typescript and then bundled with parcel.

The generated output looks correct to me, but chrome is unable to load the sourcemaps for a contentscript written in typescript. To let you reproduce the issue, I have set up this minimal sample: 
https://github.com/lhk/chrome_ts_sourcemaps

```
git clone https://github.com/lhk/chrome_ts_sourcemaps
cd chrome_ts_sourcemaps
npm install
parcel build src/manifest.json
```

This creates a `dist/` folder which can be loaded as an extension into chrome.
As you can see, the generated code contains sourcemaps:

```
console.log("I'm the contentscript");
},{}]},{},["rrAT"], null)
//# sourceMappingURL=/index.map
```

My example contains two scripts: A contentscript and a script included in the popup.html of a browseraction. They both print something to the console, which makes it easy to find them in chrome:

[image: popup log]

[image: contentscript log]

The `console.log` from the popup is already recognized as `popup.ts:1`. Chrome knows that this was a typescript file.

But the contentscript is not mapped to its original source. How can I make chrome use the sourcemap ?

Comment: As @Ihk mentioned in [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53096933/309031), the issue is not in Chrome. Chrome supports an extension source maps out of the box: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62142425/309031

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem are the sourcemap paths. The leading / is incorrect for files within folders. These files need either their full path, including the parent folder, or just their name, without a slash.

For someone also using parcel, the correct behaviour can be switched on with an additional option:

```
--public-url ./
```

The related issue is:
https://github.com/parcel-bundler/parcel/issues/2209